# How to apply to many elements: JavaScript scroll effect on element only when parent element is in viewport

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, parallax

I have a set of `100vh` sections with `child` images and text. I'd like to apply a scroll `transform` to the text to create a parallax effect that moves the text over the image. I've gotten it to work for a single element using vanilla javascript however, I can't quite get it right to apply the same effect to multiple sections with the same `class`. As it stands now, the effect is applied to all the `divs`, regardless of if their parent `section` is in the viewport.

Can you help me edit the javascript such that the child div with the `class` `scroll` only transforms if its parent `section` is in the viewport?

Thanks,

```js
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        var section = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
        var length = section.length

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var bounding = section[i].getBoundingClientRect();
            if (
                bounding.top >=0 || bounding.bottom >=0
            ) {
                const target = section[i].querySelector('.scroll');
                var rate = window.pageYOffset * -0.5;
                target.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, '+rate+'px, 0px)'
            } 
          }
    });
```

```css
/*!
Theme Name: Frozen Land
Author: Will Caulfield
Author URI: http://caulfield.co/
Description: Description
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: LICENSE
Text Domain: frozenland.co
*/
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

p, i {
  color: #9c5f89;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: calc(70px + 0.3vw);
  margin: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: calc(30px + 0.3vw);
  margin: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}

main {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f9c4cc), to(#f27aaa));
  background: linear-gradient(#f9c4cc, #f27aaa);
}

footer {
  background-color: #c9db79;
  height: 500px;
}

section.local {
  height: 300px;
}

section.hero {
  height: 100vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatIce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-15px);
            transform: translatey(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatIce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-15px);
            transform: translatey(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatText {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
            transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatText {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
            transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatLand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-5px);
            transform: translatey(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatLand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-5px);
            transform: translatey(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

.hero img {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}

div.hero {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}

.hero-ice {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
          transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatIce 6s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: floatIce 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.hero-text {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
          transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.hero-land {
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
          transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.candy-float {
  width: 50px;
}

section.cone {
  height: 100vh;
}

.cone img {
  width: 300px;
}

nav img {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

section.froyo {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.froyo img {
  width: 400px;
}

.froyo div {
  position: absolute;
}

section.toppings {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.toppings img {
  width: 400px;
}

.toppings div {
  position: absolute;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Googl Fonts -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-REHJTs1r2ErKBuJB0fCK99gCYsVjwxHrSU0N7I1zl9vZbggVJXRMsv/sLlOAGb4M" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Scripts -->

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <main>

        <section class="hero section text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
            <img class="scroll" data-rate="-0.5" src="img/logo.png" />
        </section>

        <section class="cone section text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
            <img src="img/cone.png"/>
            <div class="scroll" data-rate="-0.5">
                <h3>delicious</h3>
                <h1>ice cream</h1>
            </div>
            
        </section>

        <section class="froyo section text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
            <img src="img/froyo.png"/>
            <div class="scroll" data-rate="-0.5">
                <h3>Frozen</h3>
                <h1>Yogurt</h1>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="toppings section text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
            <img src="img/toppings.png" />
            <div class="scroll">
                <h3>and lots of</h3>
                <h1>toppings!</h1>
            </div>
        </section>

    </main>

    <footer class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center pt-5">
                <p>10911 Lindbrook Drive<br/>Los Angeles, CA 90024</p>
                <p>(310) 824-8191</p>
                <p>&copy; 2020</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>

    <script>

        // window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        //     var section = document.querySelector('.section');
        //     var bounding = section.getBoundingClientRect();
        //     if (
        //         bounding.top >=0 || bounding.bottom >=0
        //     ) {
        //         const target = section.querySelector('.scroll');
        //         var rate = window.pageYOffset * -0.5;

        //         target.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, '+rate+'px, 0px)'
        //     } else {
        //         console.log("Not in Viewport!");
        //     }
        // });

        

        // window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        //     const target = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');

            

        //     //var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
        //     //var rate = scrolled * -0.5;

        //     //target.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, '+rate+'px, 0px)'
        //     var index = 0, length = target.length;
        //     for (index; index < length; index++) {
        //         var pos = window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.rate;
                
        //         target[index].style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, '+pos+'px, 0px)';
        //     };
        // });
    </script>





    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Other Scripts -->
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`IntersectionObserver API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) to observer if elements are in view, or not. This api monitors elements that you specify and triggers a callback whenever an *observed* element enters or leaves the viewport. This way you can create a list of elements that are in the viewport.

To help with that create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Sets take any kind of type of value and stores it in a list, like a supercharged array, but only with unique values. So no element will be in there twice.

In the `intersectionCallback` check if an element leaves the viewport and add it to the set. If it leaves the screen, remove it from the set.

Then instead of looping over each `.section` loop over the set with the sections that are currently in the view. The contents of this set changes constantly depending on where the scroll position is currently.

In the `scroll` event callback calculate the position of the section relative to the top of the screen. You'll need to *offset* each transformation to the section to get the correct position of your parallax elements.

I hope this helps you out.
Let me know if anything here is unclear or if I didn't help you in any way.

Cheers!

### Addendum

I felt that the performance was a little janky so I looked into the code for improvements. The first one was adding a `passive listener` to the `scroll` event listener which tells the listener not to wait for `event.preventDefault()`. Because it will not wait it will cycle faster to the next time the `scroll` event is fired.

Then there are the calculations. Each time the `scroll` event is fired the offset is calculated. But the offset does not change when scrolling, so it would make sense to calculate it first and use it later when needed. The same goes for selecting the `target` element, that one also stays the same.

So I've added two [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects that hold a connection between the section and their offset + targets. So now the scroll function will get the previously calculated offset and target based on the current `section` it is looping over.

All theses additions will significantly improve the scroll performance and make your parallax effects feel smooth. I know it is a lot of code and I don't expect that everything makes sense right away, but if you want I could try to explain what everything does and why/how you use it.

```js
const inViewSections = new Set();
const offsetMap = new Map();
const targetMap = new Map();

function calculateOffsetsOfSections(sections, map) {
  const bodyTop = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  sections.forEach(function(section) {
    const sectionTop = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const offset = sectionTop - bodyTop;
    map.set(section, offset);
  });
}

function mapTargetsOfSections(sections, map) {
  sections.forEach(function(section) {
    const target = section.querySelector('.scroll');
    if (target !== null) {
      map.set(section, target);
    }
  });
}

function observeSections(sections, observer) {
  sections.forEach(function(section) {
    observer.observe(section);
  });
}

function intersectionCallback(entries) {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting === true) {
      inViewSections.add(entry.target);
    } else {
      inViewSections.delete(entry.target);
    }
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback, {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: [0]
});

let sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
calculateOffsetsOfSections(sections, offsetMap);
mapTargetsOfSections(sections, targetMap);
observeSections(sections, observer);

window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  calculateOffsetsOfSections(sections, offsetMap);
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  inViewSections.forEach(function(section) {
    if (offsetMap.has(section) && targetMap.has(section)) {
      const target = targetMap.get(section);
      const offset = offsetMap.get(section);
      var rate = Math.round((window.pageYOffset - offset) * -0.5);
      target.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + rate + 'px, 0px)';
    }
  });
}, {passive: true});
```

```css
/*!
Theme Name: Frozen Land
Author: Will Caulfield
Author URI: http://caulfield.co/
Description: Description
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: LICENSE
Text Domain: frozenland.co
*/

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

p,
i {
  color: #9c5f89;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: calc(70px + 0.3vw);
  margin: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: calc(30px + 0.3vw);
  margin: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}

main {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f9c4cc), to(#f27aaa));
  background: linear-gradient(#f9c4cc, #f27aaa);
}

footer {
  background-color: #c9db79;
  height: 500px;
}

section.local {
  height: 300px;
}

section.hero {
  height: 100vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatIce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-15px);
    transform: translatey(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatIce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-15px);
    transform: translatey(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatText {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
    transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatText {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
    transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatLand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-5px);
    transform: translatey(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatLand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-5px);
    transform: translatey(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

.hero img {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}

div.hero {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}

.hero-ice {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
  transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatIce 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: floatIce 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.hero-text {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
  transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.hero-land {
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
  transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.candy-float {
  width: 50px;
}

section.cone {
  height: 100vh;
}

.cone img {
  width: 300px;
}

nav img {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

section.froyo {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.froyo img {
  width: 400px;
}

.froyo div {
  position: absolute;
}

section.toppings {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.toppings img {
  width: 400px;
}

.toppings div {
  position: absolute;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <!-- Googl Fonts -->

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-REHJTs1r2ErKBuJB0fCK99gCYsVjwxHrSU0N7I1zl9vZbggVJXRMsv/sLlOAGb4M" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Scripts -->

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main>

    <section class="hero section text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
      <img class="scroll" data-rate="-0.5" src="img/logo.png" />
    </section>

    <section class="cone section text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
      <img src="img/cone.png" />
      <div class="scroll" data-rate="-0.5">
        <h3>delicious</h3>
        <h1>ice cream</h1>
      </div>

    </section>

    <section class="froyo section text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
      <img src="img/froyo.png" />
      <div class="scroll" data-rate="-0.5">
        <h3>Frozen</h3>
        <h1>Yogurt</h1>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="toppings section text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
      <img src="img/toppings.png" />
      <div class="scroll">
        <h3>and lots of</h3>
        <h1>toppings!</h1>
      </div>
    </section>

  </main>

  <footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      </div>
      <div class="col text-center pt-5">
        <p>10911 Lindbrook Drive<br/>Los Angeles, CA 90024</p>
        <p>(310) 824-8191</p>
        <p>&copy; 2020</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">

      </div>
    </div>

  </footer>

  <script>
    // window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    //     var section = document.querySelector('.section');
    //     var bounding = section.getBoundingClientRect();
    //     if (
    //         bounding.top >=0 || bounding.bottom >=0
    //     ) {
    //         const target = section.querySelector('.scroll');
    //         var rate = window.pageYOffset * -0.5;

    //         target.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, '+rate+'px, 0px)'
    //     } else {
    //         console.log("Not in Viewport!");
    //     }
    // });



    // window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    //     const target = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');



    //     //var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    //     //var rate = scrolled * -0.5;

    //     //target.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, '+rate+'px, 0px)'
    //     var index = 0, length = target.length;
    //     for (index; index < length; index++) {
    //         var pos = window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.rate;

    //         target[index].style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, '+pos+'px, 0px)';
    //     };
    // });
  </script>





  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Other Scripts -->
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Emiel, thanks for the help. It does seem to be working better. The issue now is,  the text divs seem to be way above their intended starting place. With 'And lots of toppings' it is most obvious. You can see it is meant to be below the last image (right above the green) but the js has it up above the second to last image, even before the transform is active. Any idea why?

Comment: Because each section has a different position relative to the top, you'll need to account for the offset of the transformations based on the `offsetTop` of each section. The `pageYOffset` will keep counting upwards and without any compensation will set the same transform value to each of `.scroll` items causing them to fly out of the screen. I've added the fix to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Emiel. That works. It's really helpful, I'll use this to learn. Thanks!

Comment: @EmielZuurbier you're a legend for this